# Role of "set" in windows cmd

Tags: windows, path, dos

I've noticed that changing the path using `set path=%path%;toto` and just `path=%path%;toto` seemed to have the same effect.

Could you please point out the difference, if any ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is none. `path` is an important environment variable controlled by its own command, but since it's simply a variable, `set` works just as well.